# Programmatically added image button + click

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I have a method where I am creating some image buttons.
I added below line:
btnCity.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(btnCity_Click);
to the method to code the click event.

On @Jacek's request adding code where buttons are added:

```
private void LocateCities()
{
IDBManager dbManager = new DBManager(DataProvider.SqlServer);
dbManager.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=db;  Integrated Security = SSPI;";
try
{
    dbManager.Open();
    dbManager.CreateParameters(2);
    dbManager.AddParameters(0, "@Function", "All");
    dbManager.AddParameters(1, "@Team", "All");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Stuff");
    ds = dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_select_staff_and_cities");                    

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        int xaxis = Convert.ToInt32(dr["xaxis"]) ;
        int yaxis = Convert.ToInt32(dr["yaxis"]) ;
        int textxaxis = xaxis + 30;
        int textyaxis = yaxis - 10;

        ImageButton btnCity = new ImageButton();
        btnCity.ImageUrl = "~/Images/cyanball1.gif";
        btnCity.Height = 10;
        btnCity.Attributes.Add("style", "Z-INDEX:100; POSITION:relative; left:" + xaxis + "px; TOP:" + yaxis + "px; Left:10px;Right:10px");

        Label lblCity = new Label();
        lblCity.Text = dr["city"].ToString();
        lblCity.Attributes.Add("style", "Z-INDEX: 100;POSITION:relative; left:" + textxaxis + "px; TOP:" + textyaxis + "px");

        PanelMap.Controls.Add(lblCity);
        PanelMap.Controls.Add(btnCity);    
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    dbManager.Dispose();
}
}
```

I also created below method to handle click event:

```
 void btnCity_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
     ImageButton btnCity = (ImageButton)sender;
     Response.Write("works");
 }
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions how it should look like?

Comment: Does debugger enter into your method?

Comment: Always clarify, "It doesn't work."  What didn't work?  Did you get an error, did you get a different output than what was expected, if so, what was the specific difference, etc.  Also, in this case be sure to explain how you've observed what is/isn't working; it's possible you observed behavior improperly even though it was working.

Comment: If you create Dynamic controls - you need to recreate them on every postback - do you do that?

Comment: It's worth noting that most instances of adding controls dynamically in ASP doesn't need to be done, and it's actually easier and more effective to avoid it.  Consider using a `DataGridView` or, in this case, a `Repeater` to specify a template and then bind your dynamic data to that template.  I find it's much easier to work with than dynamically created controls.

Comment: Paste code where you create your control

Comment: @Servy - According to the code btn_Click method should display "works" after clicking the button but it doesn't

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter - could You please clarify what You mean?

Comment: @Servy - thank You for advice. I will look into this. Do Yoyu have any simple code or link?

Comment: I think that when I am trying to click the image button it doesn't exists anymore. I am trying to figutr it out that button will exist when I click on it. Could You please help me with this?

Comment: @user2027004: That call to `LocateCities()` needs to be made in Page_Load() event on every page load for buttons and their events to persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the prolem. The method where cities were aded to the page was in if(!Page.IsPostBack) only. I added it to else and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

When doing Response.Write you need to call Response.Clear first and Response.End after.

Also, I have generally found that putting an img tag inside a linkbutton works better than an image button.